# Does Boost.Spirit or Antlr support Left-recursive grammars

Tags: c++11, antlr, boost-spirit

In my experience, forcing a grammar representation to not be left-recursive tends to be unintuitive or cumbersome in many cases.

I am surveying various parser generator frameworks and I am currently reading about Antlr and Boost.Spirit.

Do either of them support left-recursive grammars? In general, which one supports more powerful grammars?

Thanks!

Comment: Boost spirit does not support left recursive grammar: http://boost-spirit.com/old_docs/v1_6/doc/faq.html

Answer (score 2):

I'll google that for you. Yep, ANTLR 4 supports directly left recursive rules. https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Left-recursive+rules

Comment: I think you lied about the Googling. Please do not lie on SO.

Comment: He might have googled it regardless. This asks for further investigation.

Comment: In general, which one supports more powerful grammars?

Comment: ANTLR 4 accepts any context free grammar that does not contain hidden or indirect left recursion. Moreover, it supports semantic predicates to resolve ambiguities during the parse. Consummately, I can handle even some context-sensitive languages. I don't know about Spirit.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit Both are unlimited. But Spirit makes you work really hard for anything not naturally supported as PEG. They have very different application areas. Spirit is nice for zero-tooling ad-hoc (rapid) development. I'd personally consider hand-rolling a parser for a full-blown language (with a stable grammar). Or use ANTLR.

Comment: @sehe Um I was trying to get the author to expand his answer so that it addresses the question